# Why is TaskAwaiter not awaitable?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

### Context

I was playing with https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading, and in particular its analyzers, and they have a rule that you should not await a task if it has was created in a different context.

In my program, i am using an extension method `AutoHandleExceptionAsync` which automates the exception handling of Tasks, and that method is supposed to simply be chained after the async method which returns the Task. Of course, `AutoHandleExceptionAsync` should either await the Task, or return the Task directly. Something like :

```
public static async Task AutoHandleExceptionAsync(this Task task)
{
    task.ContinueWith(
            HandleException,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default)
        .Forget();
    await Task;
}
```

VSThreading's analyzer complain that i should not await or return the Task since i didn't create it. Since this is an extension method, i feel like it could be considered a bug in the analyzer, but that's another topic.

In order to circumvent the warning, i thought of returning the awaiter for the Task directly. Then i noticed that `TaskAwaiter`, by default, can't be awaited.

### Actual Question

I can make the awaiter awaitable with a simple extension method :

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this TaskAwaiter awaiter) => awaiter;
```

I was worried it might create an infinite loop of sorts, but in a simple test it seemed ok. If it just works, i wonder why this wasn't implemented by default. Could there be some scenario where this breaks things ?

Comment: that's like asking "why can't I use `foreach` on an enumerator (the thing returned from `GetEnumerator()`)?" - the answer is simply: *because that's not it's job or the intended usage*; if you want to circumvent the warning in this case: there are attributes or `#pragma` for that - no analyzer can cover every possible nuance or niche; they are advisory only, and even if they're right 99% of the time: that 1% still happens

Comment: I think that a more interesting question is: why the heck we shouldn't `await` a task, if it was created in a different context? What's the problem with that? Is this a generally applicable guideline, or it applies strictly to the Visual Studio codebase and its extensions?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Afaik, VSThreading is based on a JoinableTask concept, and uses a JoinableTaskFactory to switch between contexts safely and avoid deadlocks. It looks a lot cleaner and more robust than the raw TPL to me, even outside of the VS extensions environment. Here's the doc for this rule in particular : https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md

Comment: @cboittin IMHO if they want us to use the `JoinableTaskFactory` everywhere, they should write lengthy articles and blog posts explaining what are the pitfalls of the "old way of doing things", and what are the advantages  that the `JoinableTaskFactory` brings to the table. Just throwing out an analyzer and hopping that the folks will got the memo is not enough. Personally I'm disabling this silly, to my eyes, analyzer in all my Visual Studio projects. In the .editorconfig file: `# VSTHRD003: Avoid awaiting foreign Tasks` `dotnet_diagnostic.VSTHRD003.severity = none`